# How to enable mouse cursor in linux virtual console?

Tags: mouse, cursor, virtual-console

I am currently on Ubuntu 18.04, and I've been wondering how to enable cursor in virtual console.

I know there is software called 'gpm' (general purpose mouse) which is used for copying & pasting text, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I need a mouse that would interact with console apps, such as vim. When I have my graphical interface turned on, and I have vim in a console window, I can easily click some text and vim cursor goes there.

Is there any software for Linux / Linux setting, that would make it possible to interact with console apps in virtual console, even if cursor is a clumsy rectangle?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey, I managed to discover how does the cursor work (at least on ssh)
On every mouse button it sends 3 signals in ASCII meaning as follows:

1. Mouse action (` ` on left click, `"` on right click, `!` on wheel click, `#` for release(for all clicks), ``` on scroll up, 'a' on scroll down)

2, 3 : x, y position in console, where !! is 0, 0 (upper right corner) of console
These info might be helpful